# Converting a text file to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I need to convert a csv file into a dictionary.The input file is 4 columns and about food from Chick Fila.

I want the dictionary to return something like this:

```
{ “Spicy Chicken Sandwich” : (3.99,  460, 'Entrees'), “Grilled Chicken Sandwich” : (5.15, 320, 'Entrees'),  “Market Salad” : (8.19,  250,  'Salads') }.
```

it is the item, price, calories, and type

I have tried so many times to figure it out. I am in an intro to python class. So far I have this code:

```
 def read_file(filename):

    with open("menu1.csv") as f:

        for line in f:
```

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: I am super new to python. How would I use that

Comment: it is 4 columns. First column is item, then price, calories, and Type.

Comment: The Key is the Item and the value needs to be a tuple that contains the price (float), calories(int), type(str)).

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: okay i see, gotcha

Answer (score 1):

You can do this nicely using Pandas.

considering CSV file like:

```
╔══════════════════════════╦══════╦═════╦═════════╗
║           Name           ║  H1  ║ H2  ║   H3    ║
╠══════════════════════════╬══════╬═════╬═════════╣
║ Spicy Chicken Sandwich   ║ 3.99 ║ 460 ║ Entrees ║
║ Grilled Chicken Sandwich ║ 5.15 ║ 320 ║ Entrees ║
║ Market Salad             ║ 8.19 ║ 250 ║ Salads  ║
╚══════════════════════════╩══════╩═════╩═════════╝
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("menu1.csv")

df = df.set_index(<column you want as keys>)

result = df.to_dict('index')
```

This gives you something that looks like `{index -> {column -> value}}`, so to get it to the final form `{index -> (values)`} you can iterate:

```py
result = {key: tuple(val.values()) for key, val in result.items()}
```

**output:**

`{'Spicy Chicken Sandwich': (3.99, 460, 'Entrees'), 'Grilled Chicken Sandwich': (5.15, 320, 'Entrees'), 'Market Salad': (8.19, 250, 'Salads')}`

Comment: pciunkiewicz,clear answer, just some more explanation added to make it more clear if you accept